# how to echo/ print a statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database which stores an activity type `(swimming, running, soccer, tennis and basketball)under task_cstm`.

Another database stores salesman name, date_start and date_due stored in tasks.

When I run on `phpMyAdmin`,

```
SELECT COUNT( tasks_cstm.activity_type_c ) FROM tasks_cstm
LEFT JOIN tasks ON tasks.id = tasks_cstm.id_c
where tasks_cstm.activity_type_c ="swimming" and assigned_user_id="abcdefg"
```

I got the result that I want: as in it will count the total number of swimming for me.

However I place this into a **.PHP** file which allows the user to select the SALESMAN and DATE to see how many activities being promoted by the salesman during the period nothing being shown:

```
    <?php
$result0 = $GLOBALS['db']->query("SELECT tasks_cstm.activity_type_c,
    COUNT( tasks_cstm.activity_type_c ) FROM tasks_cstm
    LEFT JOIN tasks ON tasks.id = tasks_cstm.id_c
    WHERE activity_type_c='swimming' AND date_start>='$st'
    AND date_due<='$dt' AND assigned_user_id='$salesman' AND t.id=tc.id_c")

$result1 = $GLOBALS['db']->query("SELECT tasks_cstm.activity_type_c,
    COUNT( tasks_cstm.activity_type_c ) FROM tasks_cstm
    LEFT JOIN tasks ON tasks.id = tasks_cstm.id_c
    WHERE activity_type_c='running' AND date_start>='$st'
    AND date_due<='$dt' AND assigned_user_id='$salesman' AND t.id=tc.id_c")

    $result2 = $GLOBALS['db']->query("SELECT tasks_cstm.activity_type_c,
    COUNT( tasks_cstm.activity_type_c ) FROM tasks_cstm
    LEFT JOIN tasks ON tasks.id = tasks_cstm.id_c
    WHERE activity_type_c='tennis' AND date_start>='$st'
    AND date_due<='$dt' AND assigned_user_id='$salesman' AND t.id=tc.id_c")

    $result3 = $GLOBALS['db']->query("SELECT tasks_cstm.activity_type_c,
    COUNT( tasks_cstm.activity_type_c ) FROM tasks_cstm
    LEFT JOIN tasks ON tasks.id = tasks_cstm.id_c
    WHERE activity_type_c='soccer' AND date_start>='$st'
    AND date_due<='$dt' AND assigned_user_id='$salesman' AND t.id=tc.id_c")

    $result4 = $GLOBALS['db']->query("SELECT tasks_cstm.activity_type_c,
    COUNT( tasks_cstm.activity_type_c ) FROM tasks_cstm
    LEFT JOIN tasks ON tasks.id = tasks_cstm.id_c
    WHERE activity_type_c='basketball' AND date_start>='$st'
    AND date_due<='$dt' AND assigned_user_id='$salesman' AND t.id=tc.id_c")


    echo "<tr><td>" . $result0 . "</td><td>" . $result1 . "</td><td>" . $result2 . "</td><td>" . $result3 . "</td><td>" . $result4 . "</td></tr>";
```

Could someone please help me and give me some guidance?

PS: As i am unable to edit my previous post, i post it here.

Thank you.

Comment: Use `var_dump($result1)` (and on the other variables) to see what they are. It's possible they are objects which aren't being translated into strings.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing semi colons after each query.

```
$result2 = $GLOBALS['db']->query("SELECT tasks_cstm.activity_type_c,
  COUNT( tasks_cstm.activity_type_c ) FROM tasks_cstm
  LEFT JOIN tasks ON tasks.id = tasks_cstm.id_c
  WHERE activity_type_c='tennis' AND date_start>='$st'
  AND date_due<='$dt' AND assigned_user_id='$salesman' AND t.id=tc.id_c");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about $GLOBALS['db'] object you had there. But in common terms, method query() still doesn't produce a result. You have to execute() it then it will produce an array. Then you iterate the array and echo the value.

```
$query  = $db->query('SQL select query goes here');
$result = $query->execute(); 
foreach($result as $s) {
   echo $r[0];
   echo $r[1];
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for all your help. i got the result that i wanted.

What i did was to add to 
...SELECT tasks_cstm.activity_type_c, COUNT( tasks_cstm.activity_type_c ) AS TOTALCOUNT(0-4) for each result.

and for every single result(0-4) i need to have another fetchbyassoc so i input

```
$r0= $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($result0);
$r1= $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($result1);
$r2= $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($result2);
$r3= $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($result3);
$r4= $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($result4);
```

and also i echo out using this

```
echo "<tr>
<td>".$r0['totalCount0']."</td>
<td>".$r1['totalCount1']."</td>
<td>".$r2['totalCount2']."</td>
<td>".$r3['totalCount3']."</td>
<td>".$r4['totalCount4']."</td>
</tr>";
```

and yes i got the answer i need. THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR ALL UR HELP (^3^)